# Sencha touch2: How to change the default checkbox cheked and unchecked images

Tags: extjs, checkbox, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

am facing a problem in changing the default check box image.
I have added two images checked.png and unchecked.png. and added two css classes for checked and unchecked. Only unchecked image is displaying but when i check it checked image is not displayed.
I have modified the default buttons by doing the same things below and it works well for buttons. But for checkbox this is not working.(pressedCls is not there in checkboxfield). Here is the small snippet for your reference.

```
   {
    xtype: 'checkboxfield',
    ui:'plain',
    checked: 'true',
    action: 'didnotassisted_Action',
    id: 'id_assignment_didNotAssisted',
    cls: 'closeout-checkbox-unchecked',
    // pressedCls: 'closeout-checkbox-checked'
    },
```

css:

```
.closeout-checkbox-unchecked{
    background-color:transparent;
    background-image:url('../images/unchecked.png');
    height: 44px;
    width: 44px;
}

.closeout-checkbox-checked{
    background-color:transparent;
    background-image:url('../images/checked.png');
    height: 44px;
    width: 44px;
}
```

If there is any different approach to complete that please help me out.Thanks in advance.

@Andrea, Here is the screen shot of what am getting after applying your code.
[image: White background]

Comment: Does !important help? [Similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11075986/can-someone-tell-me-why-my-background-image-in-sencha-touch-2-isnt-showing)

Comment: @bwags, i dont know where to add. if you can provide code it will be really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Sencha is not using a class to differentiate the checkbox status, it leverages instead the `:checked` pseudo-class selector of the checkbox.

You can change the checkbox icons adding a pseudo-element `:after` to its `.x-field-mask` sibling.

Give `ui: 'custom'` to your `checkboxfield` and add these CSS:

```
.x-field-custom .x-input-checkbox:checked  + .x-field-mask:after  {
    content: "";
    height: 45px;
    width: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 1em;
    background-image:url(http://png-4.findicons.com/files/icons/2232/wireframe_mono/48/checkbox_checked.png);
    background-size: contain;
    display: block;
}

.x-field-custom .x-input-checkbox  + .x-field-mask:after {
    content: "";
    height: 45px;
    width: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 1em;
    background-image:url(http://png-2.findicons.com/files/icons/2232/wireframe_mono/48/checkbox_unchecked.png);
    background-size: contain;
    display: block;
}
```

Tested on Sencha 2.2.1

Comment: @chipmunk Please, consider accepting my answer if you found it useful, or giving some feedback if that didn't work for you.

Comment: sorry for my late responding and thanks for answering. i tried the above snippet which you suggested and custom check box works fine but the only problem is there is small White rectangular background which doesn't look good.I tried making the background-color as well as color in css to transparent but no luck. If you have any solution please provide that. Thanks.

Comment: If you can't modify CSS to fit your needs open another question, maybe providing a screenshot, it's hard to understand what you mean by "there is small White rectangular background which doesn't look good"

Comment: i have added a screen shot of what am getting after applying your code in css.

Comment: @chipmunk Can't really be of help with that tiny screenshot only, post a complete question with a fiddle if possible. I can't provide the css you wish without even seeing how your app looks like, I gave you the logic needed to customize Sencha Touch 2 checkboxes, so I think I answered this question.